# Setting HTTP Accept header to JSON returns HTML

Tags: java, json, api, httprequest

I wrote a program in Java that requests JSON from API and stores the response as a string.

The [API](http://trolasi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that I'm using return JSON only if header `Accept` set to `application/json` otherwise it returns HTML.

I tried setting header with `setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")` but when I debugged the program, it looked like the header is actually set but for some reason it still returns HTML.

I tried to do the same thing with Postman and it worked correctly. Why would this happen?

```
    private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int read;
        char[] chars = new char[1024];
        while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
            buffer.append(chars, 0, read);

        return buffer.toString();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
}
```

I hope I've been specific enough

Comment: What is that you are getting from url in the input?

Comment: What response you are getting when running through the code, can you post it,

Comment: `<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.12.2</center>
</body>
</html>` This is the string

Comment: when you are running through postman it is redirecting to secured one https://www.trola.si/bavarski/, and when you run through the java it doesn't. That's the reason you are getting the output in html which  says site moved permanently which is in html format

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, it works now!

Comment: Try to on the interceptor in postman, and turn off the redirect in settings under General Tab. You will get to know that postman and your code gives the same result

Comment: can i post it as answer ? -@Venoox

Comment: Yeah sure @AmpatiHareesh

Comment: Came to know about internal redirect in postman, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Postman :The Postman is using the redirect internally, turn on
>   interceptor and turnoff the redirect under general tab in settings

YourCode: change the url to secured one,use protocol https

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

May be object mutation, i pass doing this way,

```
public String getJSON(String url, int timeout) {
HttpURLConnection c = null;
try {
    URL u = new URL(url);
    c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
    c.setUseCaches(false);
    c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
    c.connect();
    int status = c.getResponseCode();

    switch (status) {
        case 200:
        case 201:
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            br.close();
            return sb.toString();
    }

} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} finally {
   if (c != null) {
      try {
          c.disconnect();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
   }
}
return null;
}
```

This is a function , more genralize , pass your url in first parameter of function and for the second , pass number of millisecond you want to hit that url.